# Timer to appear on Game Screen

Tags: c#, splash-screen

I have made a countdown timer using C# on basic form window and i want it to appear on game screen i tried to set form properties but it wont work on game screen. 
how would it be done? Any Idea?

Comment: Do you mean you want it to always be on top, sort of like a fps counter.

Comment: @cdHowie: Game Screen Means during game play timer would also be on top.

Comment: Right, but is this *your* game, or somebody else's game?

Comment: @cdHowie: No its not mine any third party game.

Comment: Since most games will switch to full-screen direct-render mode, this is not something you can do easily, especially not with Winforms.  You are going to have to mess with DirectX/OpenGL at a very low level and hook into the game's buffer-switch call.

Comment: Oh k! so any other alternate or possibility ?

Comment: The only example of such thing I've ever seen is Steam, and it hook with the game code in pretty low level so I fear you're at dead end here. Sorry for the bad news!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to draw a timer into an existing DirectX or OpenGL backed game then I suggest you take a look at the following question which offers information about hooking and the ability to intercept calls along with  working with the applications draw calls. However I believe this is above the level of complexity you would wish to encounter for adding a timer.

LINK : [OpenGL/DirectX Hook - Similar to FRAPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810854/opengl-directx-hook-similar-to-fraps)

Answer (score 0):

As you don't indicate if you are using OpenGL, XNA or what I will give you a generic response.

**If it is your game**

Your splash screen should be part of the game loop. This means that will have an update() and a draw().

- In the **update** method you have to calculate the remaining time and store it in a variable or property of an object.
- In the **draw** method you should paint the remaining time.

My recommendation is that you create a TimeCounter class because seems you are also going to reuse it during game.

**If it is not your game**

- Most games will switch to full-screen direct-render mode. It is not impossible but pretty hard.
- If the game is web, then you can wrap it in IFrame or similar and put the counter