# Always on top, even in fullscreen-games

Tags: c#, overlay, topmost

How do you put a Windows Form Application on top off everything on your screen?

Just setting the topmost-property isn't enough when you're running fullscreen games.

If anyone has a solution for good old Forms i'll also be happy

I've seen many posts on this forum that say it's impossible but i know it's not couse i've seen alot of apps (fraps, teamspeak overlay, xfire, etc) that does this.

Comment: Imagine if two applications tried to do this at the same time http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx

Comment: Fraps is doing this via DirectX/OpenGL. If you're willing to use a low level graphics API it is possible, but not really in a regular windows form (excluding Form.TopMost).

Comment: Are you using MS-windows?

Comment: Comedy option : Take a screenshot of the Windows Form application, print it out, tape it to your screen.  Serious comment - Nathan is right, but glosses over the fact that this might be waaaaay easier in an unmanaged language other than C# where you have a lot more control over painting.  I doubt that teamspeak uses Winforms to do their thing - they probably had to roll a lot of their own drawing logic.

Comment: @PeteBaughman That's definitely true, in other languages this may be much more doable. I'm just speaking in the context of windows forms, since that's what was asked.

Comment: yes im using ms windows, for example game is using OpenGL, i heard some stuff like "hooking", i searched alot about hook OpenGL but i didnt really get anything useful. has anyone got some information about it? c#!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a graphics library to display something always on screen, you may want to start [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810854/opengl-directx-hook-similar-to-fraps). There are wrapper libraries available like [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) for OpenGL. If you want to go the DirectX route you'll need to load in the C++ libraries and access them using P/Invoke. There's a good tutorial to start with [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Wrappers for DirectX also exist in the form of [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/).