# How to overlay Chromium/Electron browser hosts on DirectX and OpenGL applications?

Tags: c++, opengl, directx, electron, chromium

I'm trying to display info from the Spotify API as a overlay for DirectX and OpenGL games as there is a lot of people asking for it and I needed a project for school. I've got all the design elements working in a Electron application and I now just need to make it an overlay.

The application has a couple states: Playing, Paused, Control (frees cursor to allow in game song control with a couple buttons), Connect(for when audio is played via Spotify connect rather then on the host pc) and Stopped.
If possible I would also like to have the control state toggle with a key bind.

I've had a look online and can't find anything helpful, but I do know that Discord uses something like this. From what I can see, they use C++.

Edit: [pergy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2550156/pergy) commented with this: [electron offscreen rendering](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/offscreen-rendering.md) which seems good enough.

Comment: Not that simple. See these questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994676/hooking-directx-endscene-from-an-injected-dll), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810854/opengl-directx-hook-similar-to-fraps?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Both of these don't really answer my question, yes that are about overlaying on directx and opengl, but not overlaying a chromium host on them.

Comment: Is this about [electron offscreen rendering](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/offscreen-rendering.md) ?

Comment: yep that looks good, thanks.